# Splitting an ordered list

Tags: c#, list, linq, ienumerable

I am trying to create a sorted list of lists. Where the outer "layer" is sorted  by the field BU. and the inner layer is sorted by JobNum. I have this method, and variables.

```
public List<string> ListSorter<T>(IEnumerable<T> records)where T : 
IMapToCSVSource, new()

List<IEnumerable<T>> organizedRecords = new List<IEnumerable<T>>();
List<T> shortenedRecord = new List<T>();
```

Here I am trying to create a more concise object with only 3 specific fields instead of the possible 8 that comes with the records object. BU and JobNum are set within this method.

```
foreach (var record in records)
{
    string businessUnit = "research"; //This would vary each loop, not constant as displayed
    string JobNum = "test"       //this would vary each loop, not constant as displayed
    shortenedRecord.Add(new T()
    {
        Cost = record.Cost,
        BU = businessUnit,
        JobNum = jobNum
    });
}
shortenedRecord.OrderBy(o => o.BU).ThenBy(n=>n.JobNum);
```

here, to my knowledge, now has all the records shortened and ordered by BU, then JobNum.

Now I want to Split this ordered list into sections of BU specific records and add it to organizedRecords. Such that each element of organizedRecords is a specific BU. How would I do this?

For example, say shortenedRecord is a list of 30 elements, but there is only a total of 5 unique BU values. I would like to order and SPLIT the list into their 5 respective BU values, and add it to organizedRecords.

such that:

organizedRecords[0] should be a list of 'corporate' records

organizedRecords[1] should be a list of 'research' records

where corporate and research are BU values.

I tried to explain as best I could. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: `.GroupBy(o => o.BU).ToList()`?

Comment: Yeah sounds pretty GroupBy'ish to me. also your use of terminology is confusing. I mean you are not parsing anything

Comment: Can you instead, put your input data and output data as examples

Comment: @MichaelRandall for some reason `.GroupBy` did not work for OP - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54526787/sorting-and-splitting-list-of-generics?noredirect=1#comment95856080_54526787

Comment: Please don't just re-ask your question if it gets closed. There's a reason we close duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestions, I toyed around a bit, and I found this to work as I needed it.

```
var query = shortenedRecord.GroupBy(p => p.BU).ToList();
foreach (var group in query)
{
    var ordered = group.OrderBy(x => x.JobNum);
    organizedRecords.Add(ordered);
}
```

Comment: You could do that in the one statment

Comment: can you try like this : `var query = shortenedRecord.OrderBy(x=>x.JobNum).GroupBy(x=>x.BU).ToList();`